# How are vaccines mass-produced?

Tags: virology, pathology, epidemiology

I have a background in product design and so am familiar with with how *most* things are mass-produced — food, machines, etc.  But I've been able to find very little information on how vaccines are mass-produced.

It looks like there are [4 types of vaccines](https://www.vaccines.gov/basics/types), all of which include pieces or byproducts of the virus they're intended to counteract.

If you're producing billions of vaccines, I imagine you need a tremendous amount of the virus.

How is such a mass of virus obtained? Do they just fill up tanks with a culturing agent and a sample of the virus and wait for it to grow, like a giant petri dish? Are there big vats of Coronavirus sitting in factories somewhere?

Comment: Did you read the part of the page you linked about the mRNA vaccines for covid-19?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about industrial pharmaceutical practice, not biology.

Comment: @David I would disagree with that assessment. This seems to me to be very much about "techniques in a biological ... laboratory" just for higher scale operations.  Or is this site intending to exclude all discussion of bio work beyond [MRL 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturing_readiness_level)?  Scale-up is a massively important part of biotech R&D.

Comment: @jakebeal — No. Industrial biotechnology is not laboratory biology, and the people who are able to answer questions on biology based on their biological education and research and teaching experience seldom know any more about it than an educated non-biologist with access to the Internet. And I emphasize that this is not a discussion site — it is a question and answer site. If the question is such that it is unlikely to attract objective expert answers on a SE site is should be neither asked nor answered there.

Comment: @David Your response assumes that experts from industry should not be interested in this site, not to mention experts from academia who interact with industry.

Comment: @jakebeal — "should not be interested in this site"? Not unless they have questions about problems in biology of the type this site was set up to answer. If you mean contribute answers, their historical lack of participation speaks for itself. But even if this question were on topic, it is so vague and its scope so wide that I regard it as unsuitable. There is a Help entry somewhere about answers that require a book chapter to answer.

Comment: @David I'm currently working with algae, scaling up and investigating mass production is a big part of the area and a follow up research we must do. This will give me enough information and experience to answer this kind of questions in the context of algae, so I think this question should stay open

Comment: @Hachiloni — "This will give me enough information…"? What do you mean by this. There is only one answer which in my opinion provides no information. You may well be interested in the question, but if it is on the wrong list it won't get any answers. Wishing that experts in this area visited this list to provide their expertise is unrealistic.

Comment: @David I mean that this kind of questions can be answered on this site, so closing this question will give a bad precedent. I gave an example how I could answer a question of this kind with my knowledge

Comment: @Hachiloni I'd like to invite you to commit to the proposed Synthetic Biology site, where questions like this will be clearly on-topic and welcomed: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125068/synthetic-biology?referrer=MjE2YzEyZjY2NGZiZjQyMmQxNjM4YzE1ZTgyMTBjM2M1ZThhODIyZjc0OGY4MjUwNjQzYWUyYjcxYzdjNjgyZWgojuPHgTg3aSlhs7HovzJGQ8mR63x7oTvvqF7pWvWl0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccine#Production), typically when one needs a lot of virus, it is grown in a controlled cell environment. This used to be eggs, but is moving toward cell cultures instead.  So basically yes, factories full of virus (though more like in nice discrete bioreactors than big [Joker-friendly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/136055/what-chemicals-did-the-joker-fall-into) vats).

Synthetic vaccines, such as the mRNA vaccines for COVID, do not need this step at all, since they do not actually use the virus, but can be done through cell-free biochemical reactions that replicate the mRNA directly.

Comment: I used to work in a flu vaccine manufacturing facility, and we would go through millions and millions of eggs each season, sourced from local farms. It was quite a sight to behold...